# Modifying a array with two array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

I have two different arrays of objects. One array represents all the system modules while the other displays modules the user can access.

**This is my full response currently I'm getting -** https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y233ab057

```
{
 "modules": {
      "member": {
        "actions": [
          "create",
          "edit"
        ]
      },
      "subscription": {
        "actions": [
          "create",
          "edit",
          "move_out",
          "renew",
          "void"
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

```
{
 "user_modules": {
      "subscription": {
        "actions": [
          "create",
          "edit"
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

I want to compare both arrays and if user_modules have the same actions as modules I want to return 1 in front of the action like this **create: 1** else need to return 0 like this **void: 0** **In user_modules array will not have all the details like modules array.** So based on the above two modules I need to return something like this,

```
{
 "modules": {
      "member": {
        "actions": [
          "create" : 0,
          "edit" : 0
        ]
      },
      "subscription": {
        "actions": [
          "create" : 1,
          "edit" : 1,
          "move_out" : 0,
          "renew" : 0,
          "void" : 0
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

Can someone help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a syntax error: `[ "create" : 0 ]`. Do you maybe mean `{ "create" : 0 }` ?

Comment: Your desired structure is not valid; you have an array with associative keys.

Comment: @HaoWu I update the question!

Comment: I think, you changed wrong part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to have `actions` as an object with key-value pairs, here's a solution using some array function:

```js
const modules = {
  "member": {
    "actions": [
      "create"
    ]
  },
  "subscription": {
    "actions": [
      "create",
      "edit",
      "move_out",
      "renew",
      "void"
    ]
  }
};

const user_modules = {
  "subscription": {
    "actions": [
      "create",
      "edit"
    ]
  }
};

const output = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(modules).map(([key, value]) => [key, {
  ...value,
  actions: Object.fromEntries(value.actions.map(action => [
    action, user_modules[key]?.actions?.includes(action) ? 1 : 0
  ]))
}]));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting "modules.map is not a function" error. You can find my original output here - https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y233ab057

Comment: I've updated the answer according to your input, please check the latest version

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It's working now.